# Json Formatting in ASPNET Web Api

Tags: c#, json, webapi

I am getting json like this :

```
"[{\"Id\":59,\"SuiteCode\":null,\"IsArrived\":true,\"UserId\":\"a49a10d2-fc3f-477a-b087-5b0d07545964\",\"Price\":100.0}]"
```

My c# code is :

```
List<StorageVM> storageVMList = storageServices.GetAll().Where(x => 
     x.UserId == userId).ToList();


 var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(storageVMList);
```

I want to convert json quotes not escaped.  ("[{")

```
{
"Id":59,
"SuiteCode" :null,
"IsArrived":true,
"UserId": "a49a10d2-fc3f-477a-b087-5b0d07545964",
"Price":100.0

}
```

Comment: too many changes to the question. is it a string you are getting or a json that you need to convert ?

Comment: i rolledback to original question. I need to not escaping quotes.

Comment: Hope this link will help: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: Your source json doesnt have name or email address.. how do you expect to get the desired results ?

Comment: Edited question. I need quotes not escaped

Comment: Write it to a file if you want, the escaped double quote is only in c#'s string representation. You can use it normally everywhere a json string is used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100%, but I think you want to transform the JSON objects. The easiest way to do so it using serialization/deserialization. Use Newtonsoft Json or the System.Text.Json API for this. You can find examples on the MS Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0). You can deserialize your incoming object to a class, access it's properties, and serialize it to your desired way in another class, and then serialize that class.

Comment: An editor edited my original question. I rolled back. I need to not escaped quotes. "\"\

Answer (score 0):

Your json is serialized "twice" and to get it to a proper class object, you will need to deserialize it twice as well.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public object SuiteCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsArrived { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public object Notes { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Payment_Type { get; set; }
    public object Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelivered { get; set; }
}

// First to remove extra encoding
var jsonStr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(filename));

// Second to convert it to your object.
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(jsonStr.ToString());

// Then you can use a Select statement to get your desired object... if that information is available.

public class UserObject
{
    public User user { get; set; }
    public int min_build_version { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string avatar_url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

var converted = rootObj.Select(x => new UserObject()
{
    user = new User()
    {
        id = x.UserId,
        name = x.Description
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed

```
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shops, Formatting.None);
 string contentCorrected = json.Replace(@"\", "");
var billList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> 
(contentCorrected);
```